# Delete user fingerprint in Zklib - nodejs

Tags: node.js, zkteco

I am working on a project using `zkteco` device with `zklib` nodejs library and i want to add a function that deletes user fingerprint from device . I have tried this code:

```
async deletefingerprint() {
    return await this.executeCmd(COMMANDS.CMD_DELETE_USERTEMP, '');
}
```

But it didn't work, any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the user id parameter to delete it

```
   this.executeCmd(COMMANDS.CMD_DELETE_USERTEMP, '1', '')
```